# Present & Remove XIB as UIView over KeyWindow

Tags: swift

I'm presenting a Xib over the KeyWindow as my custom alert view.

The problem I'm having is that when I present the view again (after it's been removed from superview), the button's that had targets to them still have their old actions assigned to them. So when a button is tapped, it performs it's new action and the old one.

Aside from setting up code to .removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents) from the buttons. Why are the buttons not being presented fresh when the view get's added to subview a new time?

Code in the app delegate:

```
let AlertScreen = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Alert", owner: nil, options: nil)?.last as! Alert

    func ShowAlert (LeftButton: String, RightButton: String) {

        AlertScreen.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        AlertScreen.LeftButton.setTitle(LeftButton, for: .normal)
        AlertScreen.RightButton.setTitle(RightButton, for: .normal)
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(AlertScreen)

    }
```

Then in whatever view controller I require the alert view to show over, I simply show the alert, then I assign an action such as:

```
AlertScreen.RightButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(LoadItems), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only create the view once using:

```
let AlertScreen = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Alert", owner: nil, options: nil)?.last as! Alert
```

You are presenting the save view over and over again. If you want to fresh views, you need to create a new view every time you present it.

```
var currentAlert: Alert?

func showAlert (LeftButton: String, RightButton: String) {

    removeAlert()
    currentAlert = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Alert", owner: nil, options: nil)?.last as! Alert
    currentAlert.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    currentAlert.LeftButton.setTitle(LeftButton, for: .normal)
    currentAlert.RightButton.setTitle(RightButton, for: .normal)
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(currentAlert)

}

func removeAlert() {
    currentAlert?.removeFromSuperView()
    currentAlert = nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this has solved the problem. Although I did have this warning: "Treating a forced downcast to 'Alert' as optional will never produce 'nil'" for the as! and I switched it to as? to fix this.